Can brandishing a weapon constitute assault?
In the terminology of criminal law, can brandishing a weapon constitute assault? Or is it merely a threat of assault?

united-kingdom
The legal definition of assault is to put someone in fear of receiving violence or unlawful force.
The infliction of violent physical force begins at battery, proceeds through actual bodily harm, and concludes with grievous bodily harm or wounding.
The mere "brandishing" of a firearm is certainly capable of being an assault if the brandishing is threatening, although there are alternative offences.

some jurisdictions (US sta5es lie KY for example) define assault as the actual battery.  Your definition is not universal.

@TigerGuy, that's why I tagged it as UK. The Q didn't specify a jurisdiction.

This will depend on the definition of criminal assault in the jurisdiction, but in many jurisdictions, criminal assault includes acts that threaten to apply force to another person.
E.g. Canada's Criminal Code, s. 265:

A person commits an assault when
(a) without the consent of another person, he applies force intentionally to that other person, directly or indirectly;
(b) he attempts or threatens, by an act or a gesture, to apply force to another person, if he has, or causes that other person to believe on reasonable grounds that he has, present ability to effect his purpose; or
...

As a couple of examples:

someone was guilty of assault for brandishing a bat;
someone was guilty of assault for standing up with clenched fists and saying "let's go".


california
In California the mere brandishing of a weapon may be a misdemeanor (CA PC 417). When brandished in front of law enforcement - becomes a felony. It is neither a "threat" nor an "assault", it's a separate crime on its own.

No, brandishing a weapon is not a crime without reasonable belief that it could be used. If the weapon is used to place someone in reasonable fear of a battery, it is a crime.

I know a couple of clients who might want to hire you for an appeal

Where is that supposed to apply? Plenty of countries where gun laws prohibit open carriage.

@o.m. please don't be silly or foolish. How is that relavent

@Gjg, where I live brandishing a weapon would be a crime unless I was licensed to carry it in public, which I am not (like the vast majority of my fellow citizens). That doesn't make it assault, but it makes it a crime,

What does that have to do with anything though? That is the same for everyone. It does not make sense to bring it up.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
